# javascript remove number from string (n1,n2,...)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've a string like this

```
var s="15,4,6,8,10,3";
```

I need a create a function using js like this:

notice: numbers at string are unique

```
removeNumber(4);
```

should return:

```
s="15,6,8,10,3";
```

this:

```
removeNumber(15);
```

should return:

```
s="4,6,8,10,3";
```

Comment: Split at `","`, delete element, rejoin

Comment: First, a simple search and replace with the empty string would do it. Second, you should avoid working with stringified lists -- prefer arrays instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var s = "15, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3";
function removeNumber(str, num) {
  var reg = new RegExp('(?:\\D+|^)' + num + '(?=\\D|$)');
  return str.replace(reg, '').replace(/^\D*/, '');

  // or with a single replace:
  // var reg = new RegExp('^' + num + '(?:\\D+|$)|\\D+' + num + '(?=\\D|$)');
  // return str.replace(reg, '');
}
```

This'll work for any number of whitespace separating the numbers. In fact, it'll work with anything separating the numbers. )

---

Explanation: for the given number (let's say, it's 42), the following regex is created:

```
/(?:\D+|^)42(?=\D|$)/
```

This reads as *make sure that '42' substring is*...

- either preceded by at least one non-digit symbol, or is at the very beginning of the string
- either followed by a non-digit symbol, or is at the very end of the string

These rules are necessary to prevent capturing 42 in `424` and `442` (kudos to @Newbo.O for mentioning that).

Note that non-digit symbols preceding the target number are consumed by the regex alongside the number itself. This is great in all situations - but when the number is the first one in this string, there's a complication: you actually have to remove the number along with the following symbols, not the preceding ones.

While it's possible to account for such situation in a single regex (with alternation):

```
/^42(?:\D+|$)|\D+42(?=\D|$)/
```

... it's far easier to do a final sweep with a simple pattern:

```
/^\D*/
```

... that is 'replace all the non-digit symbols at the string's beginning'.

Comment: Why the word boundaries?

Comment: To prevent removing 4 in 44.

Comment: You'll still remove 4 in 44 with that.

Comment: @Newbo.O Indeed, fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function removeNumber(n, s) {
    var xs = JSON.parse("[" + s + "]");
    var index = xs.indexOf(n);
    if (index < 0) return s;
    xs.splice(index, 1);
    return String(xs);
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NmU7C/

Comment: You can just do `s.split(",")` instead of JSON.parse. Faster, simpler and works even on old browsers that don't have JSON.parse

Answer (score -1):

try this untested:

```
var s = "15, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3";
function removeNumber(str, num) {
  var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + num + '\\b');
  return str.replace(reg, '');
 }
```

Comment: I really wonder why post your own answer if that'll be the third one in the thread, yet untested? ) It's plain JavaScript, it can be tested literally everywhere - just spend some time to make sure it's a valid answer.

Comment: sorry i dont speak very well in English but its better to use '\b' in your regex better than '\D'

Comment: No, it's not. `\b` is just an anchor, and I want to remove the whole bunch of non-digit characters preceding the target number - that should be done with `\D`.

Comment: ah ok, maybe i dont understand well the question of OP, sorry